# PostgreSQL - How can I return ids if all column values are 'A' or NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Is there a way in PostgreSQL to get id numbers where status='A' or NULL?

Say I have a table

```
+-------------+
| ID | STATUS |
+-------------+
| 1  |  'A'   |
| 1  |  null  |
| 2  |  'A'   |
| 3  |  'A'   |
| 3  |  'C'   |
+-------------+
```

and I want to get a table

```
+----+
| ID | 
+----+
| 1  |
| 2  | 
+----+
```

It's been hours since I started struggling with this.

Comment: Can you clarify the logic? "status='A'or'B'" would result in a table of 1, 2, 3. Is it that that the id should ONLY have statuses of A or B, and therefore 3 is excluded because although it has a row with A, it also has a row with C, but 2 is included because its one row has a status of A or B?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to solve. but I suppose B as null, and A,C as text so I think IN operator doesn't fit to this problem. thanks.

Comment: Again you mention B and null and again I don't understand this. Are you trying to say that you are not looking for statuses 'A'/'B', but 'A'/null actually?

Comment: I revised the question. sorry about making misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `distinct` and `sub-query` 
As your sample change so now query will be

```
select distinct id from the_table where id not in(
select distinct id from the_table where status not in('A') and status is not null
  )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/10edf/3

according to previous sample

```
select distinct id from the_table where id not in(
    select distinct id from the_table where status not in('A','B')
      )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2318d/10

Comment: thank you! this looks good!
Is there any solution if B is NULL?

Comment: @Taka if it helps accept and upvote for SO appreciation

Comment: if B is null same output will come

Comment: How can 'B' be null anyway?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i think he said if status B is not avail

Comment: thanks for the comment! I tried but this doesn't work when B is null...

Comment: @Taka: 'B' is a letter. It is not null. Please explain what you are talking about.

Comment: @Taka can you please give me the link where nor working ?

Comment: @Taka http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/10edf/1 CHECK THIS LINK YOUR EIDT ALSO WORK in THIS QUERY

Comment: @Zaynul thanks for the help! but it doesn't work when I have NULL in IN operator. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/10edf/5/0

Comment: why you will use null as a in see my latest code that i have edited @Taka

Comment: @Taka check my answer   As your sample change so

    select distinct id from the_table where id not in(
    select distinct id from the_table where status not in('A') and status is not null
      )

Comment: i checked and given fiddle link as well @Taka

Answer (score 4):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from the_table
group by id 
having sum( status not in ('A', 'B')::int ) = 0;
```

Or, as `not exists`:

```
select distinct t.id
from the_table t
where not exists (select 1 from the_table t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.status not in ('A', 'B'));
```

Comment: Sir your 1st query returned nothing

Comment: This should obviously be `having sum( status not in ('A', 'B')::int ) = 0`, as `true` gets converted to `1` and `false` gets converted to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select distinct id
from table_name
where status = 'A'
or status = 'B'
```

Comment: what is the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You may use such a Query( works for several brand of databases ) :

```
select ID
  from tab
 group by ID
 having sum(case when Status != 'A' and Status != 'B' then 1 else 0 end )=0;
```

According to your last edit just Replace `Status!='B'` with `Status !=''` ( or  `Status is not null`):

```
select ID
  from tab
 group by ID
 having sum(case when Status != 'A' and Status != '' then 1 else 0 end )=0;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c1aeb/12)

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff has suggested to aggregate per ID and Barbaros Özhan has done the same. It is as well the method that I prefer. Anyway for PostgreSQL I'd use `EVERY` for readability:

```
select id
from mytable
group by id
having every(status = 'A' or status is null);
```